Why does std::string get corrupted when called from within a class?
I wanted to consult you about a problem I can't understand. I have a code similar to this:
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "LocaleText.h"

PyObject* GetLocaleText(PyObject* poSelf, PyObject* poArgs)
{
    char* arg;

    if (!PyTuple_GetString(poArgs, 0, &arg))
        return Py_BuildException();

    for (const auto& pair : localeTexts)
    {
        if (pair.first == arg)
        {
            return Py_BuildValue("s", pair.second.c_str());
        }
    }
    return Py_BuildNone();
}

void initlocaletext()
{
    static PyMethodDef s_methods[] =
    {
        { "GetLocale",  GetLocaleText,  METH_VARARGS}, 
        { NULL, NULL,   NULL },
        
    };

    PyObject* poModule = Py_InitModule("getLocale", s_methods);
}

and class:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class LocaleTextList
{
    public:
        std::string test_title = "Türkçe karakterler: ÇĞİÖŞÜ";
};

//////////
const static std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> localeTexts =
{
    { "TEST_TITLE", "İĞŞÜ" },
};

With this line, the Turkish characters in the text I send to Python are corrupted:
return Py_BuildValue("s", pair.second.c_str());


If I try to use the u8 prefix on my string literal, it is even worse:

However, if I define the std::string data as statically in the same .cpp file and in the same function and send it, it works without any problems:
PyObject* GetLocaleText(PyObject* poSelf, PyObject* poArgs)
{
    std::string test_title = "Türkçe karakterler: ÇĞİÖŞÜ";
    return Py_BuildValue("s", test_title.c_str());
}


When I call it from within the class, the characters are corrupted.

Is your C++ source saved in UTF-8?

@MarkTolonen Yes. The project supports utf-8.

@cvaqabond Just because the project "supports UTF-8" doesn't tell us whether or not the .cpp file itself is encoded in UTF-8, or if the compiler is being told to interpret the .cpp file as UTF-8, etc. Is that actually the case? I would suggest using the u8 prefix to force a UTF-8 string literal, ie: u8"İĞŞÜ", and use std::u8string instead of std::string, if you have it available. But, that being said, what exactly is "corrupted"? What are you seeing on the Python side? Please [edit] your question to include the Python code and what you are seeing from it.

@RemyLebeau
I am using C++20 but I cannot use std::u8string.
When I use the code as shown above, it looks like this:
https://i.ibb.co/820X3wh/Ekran-g-r-nt-s-2024-08-15-223506.png
If I clean the function content and use a fixed and static definition, it works fine:
CODE: https://i.ibb.co/gzkBdkm/Ekran-g-r-nt-s-2024-08-15-224838.png
TEXT: https://i.ibb.co/YdWGzpw/Ekran-g-r-nt-s-2024-08-15-224253.png
And when I use u8:
https://i.ibb.co/bbNW7Q8/Ekran-g-r-nt-s-2024-08-15-224538.png

İĞŞÜ is encoded in UTF-8 as the following byte sequences:
İ -> 0xC4 0xB0
Ğ -> 0xC4 0x9E
Ş -> 0xC5 0x9E
Ü -> 0xC3 0x9C
Ä°ÄžÅžÃœ is what happens when those same bytes are misinterpreted as Latin-1 characters instead of as UTF-8, eg:
0xC4 = Ä, 0xB0 = °
0xC4 = Ä, 0x9E = ž
0xC5 = Å, 0x9E = ž
0xC3 = Ã, 0x9C = œ
The string itself is properly UTF-8, but the bytes are simply being handled wrong. Double-check that the bytes being pointed to by pair.second.c_str() are actually the bytes shown above. If they are then the problem is elsewhere.
Ã„Â°Ã„Å¾Ã…Å¾ÃƒÅ“ is what happens when those same bytes above are misinterpreted as individual Unicode characters and re-encoded a second time as UTF-8, eg:
0xC4 -> U+00C4 -> 0xC3 0x84, 0xB0 -> U+00B0 -> 0xC2 0xB0
0xC4 -> U+00C4 -> 0xC3 0x84, 0x9E -> U+009E -> 0xC2 0x9E
0xC5 -> U+00C5 -> 0xC3 0x85, 0x9E -> U+009E -> 0xC2 0x9E
0xC3 -> U+00C3 -> 0xC3 0x83, 0x9C -> U+009C -> 0xC2 0x9C
And then those resulting bytes are misinterpreted as Latin-1:
0xC3 = Ã, 0x84 = „, 0xC2 = Â, 0xB0 = °
0xC3 = Ã, 0x84 = „, 0xC2 = Å, 0x9E = ¾
0xC3 = Ã, 0x85 = …, 0xC2 = Å, 0x9E = ¾
0xC3 = Ã, 0x83 = ƒ, 0xC2 = Å, 0x9C = “
The only way I can think of that happening with the u8 prefix is if the compiler is misinterpreting u8"İĞŞÜ" as if it were u8"\xC4\xB0\xC4\x9E\xC5\x9E\xC3\x9C" instead.
Either way, this feels like you have encoded the .cpp file as UTF-8, but are not telling the compiler to parse the file as UTF-8, such as with MSVC's /utf-8 flag, or equivalent if you are using a different compiler.

Actually I noticed something very strange. I think the problem is not related to the compiler. It seems to be a problem with the transfer to Python. Because when I try to print it as an error with the TraceError() function while transferring to Python, it appears without any problems in the error.txt file.
That is: I print an error like TraceError("%s", pair.second.c_str()); one line below the pair.second.c_str() section, and the Turkish character is written to the error file without any problem. I think things just got more complicated.

@cvaqabond I don't know what TraceError() is, but it sounds like it is just dumping the raw string data as-is to the log file, and if the string is UTF-8 proper and you are viewing the log as UTF-8 then you will see the correct characters as expected
